How can I fetch the extra field from the JPA specification result
I have a table called Job in my database, I want to prepare a query using JPA Specification, to get a count of Jobs from the Media users using Count and groupBy, after generating the result I will find a new field return from a database side called mediaCount for example. Still, I can't access it from the entity, because I don't have this field to lay the data inside.
I will put some codes and SQL queries to explain my idea and the problem I face.
The JPA Specification method
Expression<Long> countExpression = criteriaBuilder.count(root.get("mediaId"));

            query
                    .multiselect(countExpression, root.get("mediaUsername"), root.get("mediaPhotoLink"))
                    .groupBy(root.get("mediaId"))
                    .orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(countExpression));

and the SQL query will be like the following
SELECT COUNT(MediaID), media_username, mediaPhotoLink, MediaID
FROM JOB
GROUP BY MediaID;

and the result should look like the following
MediaIDCount ==  media_username == mediaPhotoLink == MediaID
and the entity has these fields
    @Column(name = "media_id", nullable = false)
    private Long mediaId;

    @Column(name = "media_username")
    private String mediaUsername;

    @Column(name = "media_email")
    private String mediaEmail;

    @Column(name = "media_photo_link")
    private String mediaPhotoLink;

finally, you can see from the above table and entity the small difference depends on the entity table the difference is MediaIDCount is missing in the Job entity.

Use a DTO for this not the entity.

I use the JPA Repository directly without use of entityManager, so the data will be returning as an entity first.

I strongly suggest a read of the documentation for the tooling you are using. There is no need to return an entity first and then map.
